# Python - Pulling items from one list while looping over another list

Tags: python, for-loop, pygame, nested-loops

All,

I can post the rest of my code if that helps. I've got a pygame version of Asteroids, but I'm using a histogram of words from a text file. I'm creating a dictionary [hist] with the words as keys, and the number of occurrences as values.

When I create my word instances, I want to use the word and the value. I've tried sticking another loop in the `for w in range(len(hist))` loop, and now recursion, but with recursion I get no values and with another loop I get only the last key and value put in for each instance of w.

```
class Word(object):
    def __init__(self, color, pos, radius, speed, heading, term, font, screen):
        self.color = color
        self.x = pos[0]
        self.y = pos[1]
        self.radius = radius
        self.speed = speed
        self.heading = heading
        self.term = term
        self.font = font
        self.screen = screen

    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.circle(surface, self.color, (int(self.x),int(self.y)), self.radius)
        hist_text = self.font.render(self.term, True, (0, 128, 0))
        self.screen.blit(hist_text, (int(self.x) - hist_text.get_width() // 2, int(self.y) - hist_text.get_height() // 2))

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.speed * math.cos(self.heading)
        self.y += self.speed * math.sin(self.heading)

    def checkBounds(self):
        """ wrap around screen """

        if self.x > width:
            self.x = 0
        if self.x < 0:
            self.x = width
        if self.y > height:
            self.y = 0
        if self.y < 0:
            self.y = height

def first(lst):
    if lst == []:
        return 0
    else:
        print(lst[0])
        return first(lst[1:])   

for ele in hist:
    term_keys = hist.keys()
    sizes = hist.values()

for w in range(len(hist)):
    color = (220,0,0)
    radius = 33
    for ele in sizes:
        radius = 3 * ele
        font = pygame.font.Font(None, 33 * int(ele))
    print radius
    x = 0
    y = 0
    speed = random.randint(1,5)
    heading = random.uniform(0, math.pi*2)
    for ele in term_keys:
        term = ele
    screen = screen
    w = Word(color, (x, y), radius, speed, heading, term, font, screen)
    words.append(w)
```

Comment: why do you need the loop  `for ele in hist:` it's a normal assignment of `hist.keys` & `hist.values`

Comment: i am not entirely sure i understand what you are going for here - are you having issues counting the number of occurances of a given word?  have you looked at the Counter class implementation in python?

Comment: w = Word(color, (x, y), radius, speed, heading, term, font, screen) // what does this line return val to w ? and also , you are looping with value w , you should not change value w within the loop

Comment: I don't need the for ele in hist: loop, but it's not causing any problems at the moment.

Comment: I'm not having an issue counting the word occurrence, but I am having an issue with pulling the item from that list of words and assigning it to "term" in each "w".

Comment: Can you ask a clear, explicit question?  It's really hard to figure out what you want here.

Comment: I'm creating a list of objects with a for loop. How do I assign a value to one of the object attributes from a list? Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Like many of the commenters, I'm really not clear on what you want here.  If what you're looking to do is create a dicitionary `hist` that counts the number of occurrences of the words, in the file, use `collections.Counter`.  An example:

```
>>> t = '''All,
...
... I can post the rest of my code if that helps. I've got a pygame version of A
steroids, but I'm using a histogram of words from a text file. I'm creating a di
ctionary [hist] with the words as keys, and the number of occurrences as values.

...
... When I create my word instances, I want to use the word and the value. I've
tried sticking another loop in the for w in range(len(hist)) loop, and now recur
sion, but with recursion I get no values and with another loop I get only the la
st key and value put in for each instance of w.'''
>>> t = t.split()
>>> collections.Counter(t)
Counter({'the': 7, 'and': 5, 'I': 5, 'of': 5, 'a': 4, 'in': 3, 'with': 3, 'anoth
er': 2, 'as': 2, 'for': 2, "I've": 2, 'get': 2, 'but': 2, 'words': 2, "I'm": 2,
'word': 2, 'my': 2, 'loop': 2, 'Asteroids,': 1, 'code': 1, 'text': 1, 'each': 1,
 'When': 1, 'number': 1, 'rest': 1, 'key': 1, 'put': 1, 'occurrences': 1, 'want'
: 1, 'post': 1, 'if': 1, 'instance': 1, 'use': 1, 'from': 1, 'recursion,': 1, 'v
alue.': 1, 'create': 1, 'loop,': 1, 'file.': 1, 'range(len(hist))': 1, 'to': 1,
'only': 1, 'version': 1, 'pygame': 1, 'w.': 1, 'helps.': 1, 'got': 1, 'tried': 1
, 'creating': 1, 'dictionary': 1, 'that': 1, 'All,': 1, 'keys,': 1, 'histogram':
 1, 'value': 1, '[hist]': 1, 'using': 1, 'now': 1, 'last': 1, 'no': 1, 'instance
s,': 1, 'values': 1, 'can': 1, 'w': 1, 'recursion': 1, 'sticking': 1, 'values.':
 1})
```

Comment: I've created a dictionary hist, but I'm trying to take each word and each occurrence value from the dictionary hist and plug them into object attributes. Basically I'm creating a wordcloud version of Asteroids.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, so dumb. I got it working by adding a count

```
count = 0
for w in range(len(hist)):
    color = (220,0,0)
    x = 0
    y = 0
    size = sizes[count]
    term = term_keys[count]
    speed = random.randint(1,5)
    heading = random.uniform(0, math.pi*2)
    screen = screen
    radius = 5 * size
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, int(size) * 5)
    print radius
    print term
    w = Word(color, (x, y), radius, speed, heading, term, font, screen)
    words.append(w)
    count += 1
```